# How to display email inbox for Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, AOL using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I would like to at least display items from the email inbox.
(Similar to the new Yahoo homepage)

Is this possible without server-side? How does Yahoo do it?

Any client-side solutions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: What information more do you need?
I would like to know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) for this functionality.

Also there **must be a server side language**.

Comment: That's right. The server must at least provide an API so you can send specific commands to the server and receive what you need. If there is none, I'm afraid it is not possible (or at least extremely difficult and error prone)